# How to get function pointer from many functions and pass args to it?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have many defined functions as follows, all return an `int`

```cpp
int fn1(int x) {
    return x;
}

int fn2(std::string x, int y, std::string z) {
    // process string x and z
    int x1 = process(x);
    int z1 = process(z);
    return x1 + y + z1;
}

// ... and many more similar functions
```

For some reasons, I need to implement a wrapper to call the above functions by function names,

```
int wrapper(std::string fn_name, some_struct_t data, std::vector<std::string> field_names) {
    a_fn_ptr_type fn_ptr = nullptr; // <q1>: is this a right way to do?

    // by fn_name, decide which fn to call
    if (fn_name == "fn1") {
        fn_ptr = &fn1;
    }
    if (fn_name == "fn2") {
        fn_ptr = &fn2;
    }
    ...

    // given field_names, get the field from data, pass them to fn_ptr as args
    for (auto field_name: field_names) {
        std::any value = get_from_data(data, field_name, field_type); // field_type will be updated by this call, so that we know the value type.
        
        // <q2>: but how to pass each value as arg to fn_ptr here?
         
    }
}
```

The above code demonstrate what I want to achieve, and I have 2 questions (as pointed by `<q1>` and `<q2>`).

I'm not sure if the code is the right way to go, hope to get some advice from people, thanks!

Comment: you cannot have one pointer to function that points to either of the two. The functions are of different type. What is your actual requirement? Looks like using a function pointer isnt the solution

Comment: I am with @idclev463035818 in thinking that we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is where `std::map` can come in handy vs. a long gauntlet of `if` statements. That being said this problem is usually handled with subclassing vs. slinging around function pointers.

Comment: @tadman It would be, if the functions were not so differently prototyped...

Comment: @Yunnosch That'll need to be addressed regardless of the approach.

Comment: Looks more like you want a _Dispatcher_ at an intermediate Level. This could hold maps of function pointers to resolve the string keys, and decide where to get the necessary number and values of parameters from.

Comment: @tadman True. But the answer to the difference problem might change so that the use of pointers (from a map or not) is dropped.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your comments. Since all the `fn*` are already defined by some other people, I cannot control the signature of them, and what I want to do is to have a convenient wrapper to call them by choice.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm a big fan of a simple base class that implements a callable interface, where there's some consistency enforced there, but since we're living in 2020 we can also use `std::function` or lambdas.

Comment: Call them *how*? They take totally different arguments. At the very least you need to write some kind of adapter that can convert your *stuff* to the arguments those functions take.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, exactly a Dispatcher, thanks for bringing up this term.

Comment: @tadman Yes, unfortunately. And since they have different types / numbers of args, I was thinking if I could use `std::any` and `std::vector` to handle this issue, but didn't make it though.

Comment: `std::map` full of of lambdas that take consistent arguments and call these wonky functions with their whack arguments.

Comment: @tadman, could you please elaborate on this part: "At the very least you need to write some kind of adapter that can convert your stuff to the arguments those functions take." ?

Comment: @avocado In case that your functions have optional parameters they could be called with, you'd still need overloads for these, since defaults won't change the function signatures.

Comment: Well, like if `x` needs to be an `int` for one, then you have code that extracts that string and converts it, then calls that function. For the other you pass it and other stuff in as strings. Basically you're writing a little glue layer where these lambda functions take a consistent set of arguments, then do whatever they need to do to call those irregular functions.

Comment: _@avocado_ Yes, what @tadman says: Loads of lambda wrappers.

Comment: @tadman Could any of you put down an answer below with more details?

Comment: It's late for me, so really can't, but I'm sure someone else can give a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks to tadman.
Could you please? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @avocado Hmm, well I also see that's more like asking about an XY-problem, like stated earlier. An answer won't match very good with your question (not to mention, it would go very lenghty and broad to be helpful in future research). I'd recommend you research about the theory of _Dispatcher patterns_ a bit more. Last, I don't have the time ATM to write a good and conscise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the comments:

A wrapper that takes `some_struct_t data, std::vector<std::string> field_names`. Assuming a

```
template <typename T>
T get_from_data(some_struct_t, std::string);
```

You have a function type

```
using func_t = std::function<int(const some_struct_t &, const std::vector<std::string>&)>;
```

which you can instantiate from functions via

```
template <typename... Args, size_t... Is>
auto wrap_impl(int(*func)(Args...), std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return [func](const some_struct_t & data, const std::vector<std::string>& field_names)
        { return func(get_from_data<Args>(data, field_names.at(Is))...); };
}

template <typename... Args>
func_t wrap(int(*func)(Args...))
{
    return wrap_impl(func, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

and then you can have a

```
std::map<std::string, func_t> functions;
```

Comment: That's a rough starting point for the whole thingy, yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah, the wrapper probably has to co-ordinate with the "fill args from `some_struct_t data`" to do conversions

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843708/how-to-get-function-pointer-from-many-functions-and-pass-args-to-it/63844071?noredirect=1#comment112897310_63843708) please ;-)

Comment: Thanks for providing the code examples!
I have a question, how should I use `wrap` then? Like `auto wrapped_fn1 = wrap<int>(fn1); functions["fn1"] = wrapped_fn1;` ?

Comment: @avocado pretty much. You should be able to `functions["fn1"] = wrap(fn1)`, the template arguments can be deduced from `fn1`. If a function is overloaded, you'd have to static cast to the function pointer type you want for that string.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried with `wrap(fn1)` looks fine. But got some issues with `get_from_data` function, it failed at `get_from_data<Args>(data, field_names.at(Is))...)`, saying the return type is not OK.

I'm trying to find a way to work around this.

Comment: Regarding the `get_from_data<Args>()` issue I mentioned above, I think it's because when this template function is instantiated with say `Args=int`, then the compilation fails since in `get_from_data`, there are other `if-else` branches would return say `string` type. So to make it work, I think I need to return a general type, like `std::any`, and then do an `any_cast` before passing it to the `func`, does that sound right?

Comment: The problem with wrapping values in `std::any` is you can only unwrap them to the same type. If there "should be" implicit conversions calling your functions, you'll get `bad_any_cast` thrown. Maybe wrap each case in `if constexpr(std::is_convertible_v<MemberType, T>) { return static_cast<T>(data.member); } else { throw }`

Comment: Thanks! Surely will try as you suggested

Comment: It worked well, thanks so much! Answer accepted. BTW, just out of curiousity, can we merge `wrap` and `wrap_impl` into one function? Due to the existence of `size_t... Is`, I didn't think of a possible way to merge.

Comment: @avocado indeed, you can't

Comment: This might be a bit late, but may I ask how could we use the above code to wrap class member functions? I searched on SO, and tried some tricks, but none worked. For example, I tried `wrap(std::bind(&FnClass::fn, a_FnClass_object));`, but it cannot compile.

Comment: @avocado you could use `std::function<int(Args...)>` in wrap